# How to create and use jquery UI widget factory as class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Coming from java, a class would be in its separate file if needed and look like this.

```
AClass.java
class AClass{
    public AClass{

    }
}
```

And in a different file you would create an instance

```
AClass classInstance = new AClass();
```

How can i get to the same thing with Jquery UI?
I want to have my index.html

```
<html>
   <div class='be_a_plugin'></div>
   <button class='a_class'></button>
   <script src='init.js'></script>
   <script src='implement.js'></script>
</html>
```

And my init.js file

```
//Not sure what should go here.
//How do i do this? Lets see ummm
extend $.widget("ns.plugin");?
extend $.anotherwidget;?
//I  just want all my widgets(which i intend to create each in a separate file) to be available to my implement.js and still be organized
```

And one of my classes

```
$.widget( "ns.plugin", {

// Default options.
options: {
    param1: "foo",
    param2: "bar",
    param3: "baz"
},

_create: function() {
    // Options are already merged and stored in this.options
    // Plugin logic goes here.
}

});
```

And my implement.js

```
$('.a_class').on("click",function(){
   $('.be_a_plugin').plugin(); 
});
```

Comment: Just think of each `$.widget` as a class and either load each one in separate file of put a bunch of them in one file. Nothing complicated about it. Can use build tools to minify and concatenate multiple files

Comment: Javascript is vastly different from Java I'm afraid. Basically, you have to include all the classes you'll need as separate `<script>` tags. Once you do that, they'll be in the global scope as long as you include them before anything that needs them. There isn't really a syntax to do this inside the file that needs the class. There are projects like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html#get) that will hide this from you and let you have code that's pretty organized and looks somewhat like your *init.js* example but its basically what they'll do behind the scenes.

Comment: What about a init.html that has all the script tags. Can that be included?

Comment: Sure as server side include but that would have nothing to do with javascript itself

Comment: So perhaps a index.php that includes an init.html with all the script tags

Comment: What if instead of a script tag for each file I do something like <script src='path/to/myclasses/*.js'></script> and include all files in that folder? @jeteon if such a thing exists

Comment: Unfortunately not. Look into RequireJS as I think it comes pretty close to the level of abstraction that you would like. [This blog post](https://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/) seems to be a decent intro to these systems. They tend to have a pretty steep learning curve as they are trying to abstract away a system that honestly only works the way I described in my earlier comment. As you and @charlietfl have said, you can also roll you own abstraction with server side code.

Comment: Or use `glob()` to get array of files in that directory to generate all the script tags with using php. Or store a php config file with array of scripts. Lots of ways to do it